# Channel URL Format leads to 404s for individual entries

Tags: url, routes, routing, 404-page, channels

I've broken my news channel but I don't know how I did it, or consequently to fix it.

If one clicks on 'I just installed Craft' or 'Continue reading', it will take you to the URL I specified in the Section settings using the Craft control panel, but it results in a 404.

It didn't do this at first, then (I think this is when it broke) I changed the entry URL format from `news/{postDate.year}/{postDate.month}/{slug}` to just `{postDate.year}/{postDate.month}/{slug}`. After I got the 404s assumed I couldn't do that so I changed it back, but it's still broken.

I'm quite new to this kind of thing so I apologise if I'm wasting anyone's time. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So the section's URL format is now news/{postDate.year}/{postDate.month}/{slug}?  What's the section's path to the template set to?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for this Brad. It was set to '_entry', but only after seeing your comment did it click for me that this wasn't right. I've since changed it to 'news/_entry' and it's fixed now. I don't think I can mark your comment as an answer, should I write it up myself or do you want to?

Comment: You can go ahead and answer and get the rep if you want.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that when I deleted `news/` from the entry URL format, I also deleted it from the entry template path as well because I misunderstood what that field was for (and forgot to revert that change when everything broke).

Thanks to @Brad for drawing my attention to it.